# Profiling python C extensions

Tags: python, c, profiling

I have developed a python C-extension that receives data from python and compute some cpu intensive calculations.
It's possible to profile the C-extension?

The problem here is that writing a sample test in C to be profiled would be challenging because the code rely on particular inputs and data structures (generated by python control code).

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've found my way using [google-perftools](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/). The trick was to wrap the functions StartProfiler and StopProfiler in python (throught cython in my case).

To profile the C extension is sufficient to wrap the python code inside the StartProfiler and StopProfiler calls.

```
from google_perftools_wrapped import StartProfiler, StopProfiler
import c_extension # extension to profile c_extension.so

StartProfiler("output.prof")
... calling the interesting functions from the C extension module ...
StopProfiler()
```

Then to analyze for example you can export in callgrind format and see the result in kcachegrind:

```
pprof --callgrind c_extension.so output.prof > output.callgrind 
kcachegrind output.callgrind
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that hint !! I was actually looking for the same thing. I will try.

Comment: EDIT : It works perfectly indeed ! A simple wrapper with ctypes is OK even if I get sometimes segfaults during CPU profiling (but this is "normal" and explained in the doc... I am using x86_64 :( )

Comment: Thank you very much for this little nugget. It's been very, very useful :-) What I'm seeing is that pprof (or rather, google-pprof in the package for Debian), is that I don't get as many symbols demangled as I'd do when profiling the same code with valgrind. May it be that I need to specify -pg when compiling?

Comment: The link is broken. I've found a working link here: https://github.com/google/pprof

Comment: Would in be possible to do Heap Profiling this way?

Answer (score 31):

After the comment by pygabriel I decided to upload a package to pypi that implements a profiler for python extensions using the cpu-profiler from google-perftools: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/yep

Comment: Thanks, I found this really useful and quite easy to get going with!

Comment: This is great and very easy to use. Thank you.

Comment: How to use it on windows?

Answer (score 8):

I found [py-spy](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy) very easy to use.  See [this blog post](https://www.benfrederickson.com/profiling-native-python-extensions-with-py-spy/) for an explanation of its native extension support.

**Highlights:**

- pip installable
- cpu sampling based
- no compiler flags required
- executes your program or attaches to a running process
- multiple output formats (I recommend `--format speedscope`)
- configurable sampling rate

Comment: This should be the top answer!

Answer (score 5):

One of my colleague told me `ltrace(1)`. It helped me on the same situation quite a lot.

Assume the shared object name of your C extention is `myext.so` and you want to execute `benchmark.py`, then

```
ltrace -x @myext.so -c python benchmark.py
```

Its output is like

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls      function
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
 24.88   30.202126     7550531         4 ldap_result
 12.46   15.117625     7558812         2 l_ldap_result4
 12.41   15.059652     5019884         3 ldap_chase_v3referrals
 12.41   15.057678     3764419         4 ldap_new_connection
 12.40   15.050310     3762577         4 ldap_int_open_connection
 12.39   15.042360     3008472         5 ldap_send_server_request
 12.38   15.029055     3757263         4 ldap_connect_to_host
  0.05    0.057890       28945         2 ldap_get_option
  0.04    0.052182       26091         2 ldap_sasl_bind
  0.03    0.030760       30760         1 l_ldap_get_option
  0.03    0.030635       30635         1 LDAP_get_option
  0.02    0.029960       14980         2 ldap_initialize
  0.02    0.027988       27988         1 ldap_int_initialize
  0.02    0.026722       26722         1 l_ldap_simple_bind
  0.02    0.026386       13193         2 ldap_send_initial_request
  0.02    0.025810       12905         2 ldap_int_select
....
```

Special care is needed if your shared object has `-` or `+` in its file name. These characters aren't treated as is (see `man 1 ltrace` for details).

The wildcard `*` can be a workaround such as `-x @myext*` in place of `-x @myext-2.so`.

Answer (score 4):

With [gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html), you can profile any program that was [properly compiled](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html#SEC2) and linked (`gcc -pg` etc, in `gprof`'s case).  If you're using a Python version not built with `gcc` (e.g., the Windows precompiled version the PSF distributes), you'll need to research what equivalent tools exist for that platform and toolchain (in the Windows PSF case, maybe `mingw` can help).  There may be "irrelevant" data there (internal C functions in the Python runtime), and, if so, the percentages shown by `gprof` may not be applicable -- but the absolute numbers (of calls, and durations thereof) are still valid, and you can post-process `gprof`'s output (e.g., with a little Python script;-) to exclude the irrelevant data and compute the percentages you want.

Comment: I have still some problems using this but maybe it's just my fault.
After compiling and linking (gcc) the python source the executable produces correctly the gmon.out file.
If I execute the scripts that loads the C extensions ( *.so ) compiled with -pg flags, the profiling output ( gprof /path/custom/python ,nor gprof extension.so ) doesn't show the function calls contained in the C library.
I am missing something?

Comment: gprof doesn't play nicely with dlopen(), presumably because it initializes its memory maps prior to the library being loaded.  Merely compiling with the -pg flag does nothing to help gprof if the host exectuable (in this case, python) isn't linked directly against the .so file.