# pydrake: How do I identify slow Python LeafSystem's (to possibly rewrite in C++)?

Tags: python, profiling, drake

I am prototyping a simple Drake simulation. I have some simple Python `LeafSystem`s that implement controllers, and find that without these systems, my simulation can run at realtime; however, with these systems, my simulation runs much slower than realtime.

I don't think it's the math, but instead just the overhead of Python vs. C++.

For this code: 
https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/tree/2e3865a7aefe8adc19a6ff69e84025def03da7fd/drake_stuff/python_profiling

If I try to use Python's `cProfile` and then use `snakeviz` to visualize the results, I can see that my Python code seems slow, but I can't tell how it compares to the C++ Drake code that `pydrake` is binding.

Without Python `LeafSystem`s (`--no_control`):

> [image: cprofile no control]

With the Python `LeafSystem`:

> [image: cprofile with control]

My tracepoint is in `main()`, but it does not appear in either of those.

How do I get better information about relative timing, without rolling my own timers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is best answer, but I found this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61253170/7829525

`py-spy` seems like an excellent tool for seeing relative performance information for Python code that involves CPython API extensions.

From my naive usage mentioned here: 
https://github.com/benfred/py-spy/issues/531 
https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/tree/6048da3/drake_stuff/python_profiling

I can now see more information.

Looking at interactive SVG flamegraphs from `py-spy` with default rate of 100 samples/sec:

Without Python `LeafSystem`s (`--no_control`):

> [image: pyspy no control]

With Python `LeafSystem`s:

> [image: pyspy with control]

---

Per @nicho's suggestion below, using `py-spy --native` can provide much better detail. Using Ctrl+F for `.py:`, here's what it looks like:

Without Python `LeafSystem`s (`--no_control`):

> [image: pyspy no control, native]

With Python `LeafSystem`s:

> [image: pyspy with control, native]

Comment: Note that I'm not entirely clear why the "Without Python" sample based timing is less than 100 samples (1 sec).

Comment: This worked for me after adding `--native` as an additional argument after `record`

Comment: Huh... what was the error message w/o `--native`?

Comment: No error message, but the svg did not include all the timings

Comment: Ah, sweet! Just updated w/ that flag, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As additional note, quick transcription to C++ with some Python bindings yields sufficient performance to run at real-time.

Example of the transcription from Python to C++ w/ bindings: 
[components.py](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/6048da3/drake_stuff/python_profiling/components.py) ->
[components_cc_py.cc](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/6048da3/drake_stuff/python_profiling/components_cc_py.cc)